# Cheap SSL vs Expensive SSL

Tags: encryption, ssl, certificate, public-key, private-key

I was wondering what is the different between SSL certificate from verisign,
http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/compare-ssl-certificates/index.html

which is expensive , and a certificate from godady which is cheap though,
http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx

is it like more secure or browser compatible ? they both generate a public/private and certificate keys ?

Thanks 
Alaa

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cheapest SSL certificates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968/cheapest-ssl-certificates)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all about trust. Verisign is a more highly-regarded authority than GoDaddy, so they command a higher price. Furthermore, Verisign verify the legitimacy of your organisation, whereas GoDaddy are only verifying your ownership of the domain.

Comment: Are there any functional differences?

Comment: @Martin, why do we even need trust? Isn't guaranteeing protection against man-in-middle attacks more than enough?

Comment: @Pacerier, man-in-the-middle is the least of your worries if man-at-the-other end is dodgy but has been certified by a dodgy certificate authority. Anyone can be a CA, so you need to be able to trust them.